# Javascript Async thunk

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to come up with the code to write inside the `makeThunk` function, but here I'm unable to understand how to pass the value of `cb` inside the `makethunk` function.

I want to log sum value after calling thunk with the callback!

My code looks something like this:

```
"use strict";
function addAsync(x,y,cb) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    cb(x+y);
  },1000);
};`enter code here`
var thunk = makeThunk(addAsync,10,15);
function makeThunk(){`enter code here`};
thunk(function(sum){
  console.log(sum);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you are looking for something like below:

```
"use strict";

function addAsync(x,y,cb) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    cb(x+y);
  },1000);
};

var thunk = makeThunk(10,15);

function makeThunk(num1,num2){

  return function(cb) {
    addAsync(num1,num2,cb);
  }

};

thunk(function(sum) {
  console.log(sum);
});
```

Comment: Perfect! This was what I was looking for being a newbie in JS

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Function.prototype.bind()` passing `x`, `y`, and `cb` as parameters

```js
"use strict";

function addAsync(x, y, cb) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    cb(x + y);
  }, 1000);
}

function makeThunk(fn) {
  fn()
}

var thunk = makeThunk(addAsync.bind(null, 10, 15, function(sum) {
  console.log(sum)
}))
```

Comment: I agree with this approach.I would need to additional line to execute the thunk func right

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeThunk(...args){
   return function(cb){
      args.push(cb)
      addAsync(...args)
   }
}
```

just make use of the rest/spread operator syntax which is new in es6